# How to create jpeg file with raw data

Tags: java, image

I have the raw data and want to convert and generate a jpeg file, I do that as below, but it does not work. The generated file could not be opened well.

```
    String photo="0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010200000100010000FFDB004300080606070605080707070909080A0C140D0C0B0B0C1912130F141D1A1F1E1D1A1C1C20242E2720222C231C1C2837292C30313434341F27393D38323C2E333432FFDB0043010909090C0B0C180D0D1832211C213232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232FFC00011080193012C03012200021101031101FFC4001F0000010501010101010100000000000000000102030405060708090A0BFFC400B5100002010303020403050504040000017D01020300041105122131410613516107227114328191A1082342B1C11552D1F02433627282090A161718191A25262728292A3435363738393A434445464748494A535455565758595A636465666768696A737475767778797A838485868788898A92939495969798999AA2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9AAB2B3B4B5B6B7B8B9BAC2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9CAD2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9DAE1E2E3E4E5E6E7E8E9EAF1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8F9FAFFC4001F0100030101010101010101010000000000000102030405060708090A0BFFC400B51100020102040403040705040400010277000102031104052131061241510761711322328108144291A1B1C109233352F0156272D10A162434E125F11718191A262728292A35363738393A434445464748494A535455565758595A636465666768696A737475767778797A82838485868788898A92939495969798999AA2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9AAB2B3B4B5B6B7B8B9BAC2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9CAD2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9DAE2E3E4E5E6E7E8E9EAF2F3F4F5F6F7F8F9FAFFDA000C03010002110311003F00F6FA28A29805145140051451400514514005145140051451400514514005145473DC436B0B4D712A451A8C96638028024A47758D0BC8EA883AB31C01F8D79378ABE307D9E56B6D022460320DCCC3393FECAFF535E57A978AF57D5E42F7D772DD303951249903E8338FD2B3753B16A0FA9F495D78CBC3766E526D6ECC30EAA926F23FEF9CD541F117C264E3FB613FEFD3FF00857CC6F7F719E622A3D8D345E90D8669233DF934B9A43E589F555AF8C7C397A7106B5664FA349B0FEB8AD98E449A3124522C887A3230607F115F22C573295CEF561EBEB5A7A6F88F54D2E5CE9D7F7169275D88F853F874A7CEFA8B94FAA68AF1FF000FFC68DA63B6D7AD09230AD7110C1FA95E87F0C57A9697ACE9DAD5B0B8D36F22B98CF5D8791F51D455A9264B4D17A8A28A620A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A51494A280128A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028EBD29934D1C11192460AA06492715E3FE3AF8A4AE1F4ED1A42F191896742507FBAA7A9FAFE5EB5329243516CED7C57F11346F0B1681CB5DDF01FF1EF09FBBFEF1E83F9D78678ABC71AFF008B1C8B9B81059E72B6D136D41F527935CEDC5F2CF2B3B939639214D57DE8C4E56539F7CD67ABDCD2C96C35AD9DF3F316FA1CD41F67393C1E3F4AB5B369046187A30C1A9198ECDC7E71EFD47E35484545DF1E76B30FC6944C0B6D90004F46E9565E35920C44E41EC1BA5565469818A5003FF09EC698890AC903EE53807AEDEF56149980C601C703B56747349012AD929D08EE2A682630B7964831B0CA363BD2B05CBBE647226D67C30E391C83EF5A7E1DF115DF87B5459E165CA7547C94907A6474FA8AC391B77FA420C38E185123078C3E4846EA07F09FF0A2C173E87F0BFC4AB4D4094BC91A3079DB272F1FAFCC3EF2FEBF5AF428E48E6892589D5E371B95D4E430F506BE3DD3B529EC2E53E620A9C8E6BD8FC11E3796CE6315D05FB131CCCA0FFAB6271BD4761FDE51F5A14ADA306AFAA3D868A4565750CAC195864107208F5A5AD080A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A51494A280128A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A28A00291DD63467760AAA32C4F40296B3F5ABE834ED2AE6EEE1808A08DA56CFA0FEB9C63DE93D00F36F8A3E2C9C694D6B6B32DBDBB9D8CA41F36538071FEC8C1E47D33D715E1DF3DCC9F331E7A0EF5A3E21D72EF5CD41A7B876650488E33D14139C5635CCBB104607CC7A9EE6B35AEACD5E9A124925BC2DB51958FAF5A8C5DB2B0DA11BF0A9F4DD1E6BE94048CB13DB15DB5878363441E747BD8F50074A529A45C294A5B1C4F99E728DAA5241E9D2A41E6B0E62FA95EFF00857AADA783ED4A85F2571EB5A71F836CC631101DF359BAC8D96199E31F6372C1A3E327953DEAC7F665CB60B4041038E3835ED0BE09B160410016EE074ABF07846CE188A8E47A11C52F6A2742C784FF00663B22C8C8403C64D46DA534711254943E9FC26BDCE7F075ABC451506D3C81DC1ACFFF00841C213D0AE7D3EF7D69FB50740F14F2D90F03A8C303DE976AA301B7746460D7A9DEF80BF78C5172A0646055393C05232B148C9A7ED513EC19E632C7B485CE71F75BDAB5748D425B69E378D80208EBC8AEA2E7C0572225C0C38EBED5CAEA1A3DEE8D39F3A3207F7BB535352D0995294753E82F869E215D574A92C89C1B7C794A7A85EEA3D81E9EC457755E03F08F561078AA189FFD5CE8F193E84F4FA7231F8D7BF56D17A18496A14514551214514500145145001451450014A29294500251451400514514005145140051451400514514005791FC69D61EDF4FB1D2918ABDD31B89D73CED5E114FB6727F0AF5D1C902BE59F1EEB4DADF8B751BC32168C4A62847A2A9C0FE59FC6A27D8B86F739B4600B3919C0FCAA7D374C6D46E038C919E49F5AA5187B8963B7897259B923D6BD4342D223B3B651B7240F4EA6B3A92E546D469FB4916343D1D2CE2CEDF9ABA6B5B4E4123AF5A4B1B5C95523DEB6238D7B0AE3726CF4D2515616080051C55C8E2C7E3DE9225031C55B54E3B50919C98C58F8A781ED8A78434A0107919AAB117136E78A367183520500F029D8E2AAC4DCAE500ED51B46A3B55964F5A858617247150D14881A08DC608159BAA786AD354B49219630430FCAB558F3D69CB271EB4E3614AEB63C0EEB4EBAF0978A9AD64E064346FCF2339047BD7BEF863C5B6DAEC49138115DEDE9FC3263FBBFE15C3FC4BD086ADA30BB857FD2ED7E6423A91DC579FF833C4F2699A8C4D2B1F2FEEC981CE3D47B8AE984CE3A94CFA728AA5A56A10EA7A7C7710CA2418C33018C9F5FC7AD5DAE839C28A28A0028A28A0028A28A0029452528A004A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A280313C61A99D1FC1FAADF23EC923818467B876E063F135F26DD49BA7C0249007FDF55F44FC67B868BC190C2A7026BB5DDEE02935F3BDAC66599E663C29FD6A1EE5AD8DBF0AD8F99A9A36DF963EE7B9F5AF56B2B718500702B88F07DA79AE5C70057A3DAC41556B8EB4AF23D1C2C6D0B97AD6301781C9AB2894C846D5A99783ED592376C9A3241ABD1E0AD514EA0F7AB48FB718AD22CCA68B1B41E29DB062A157E6A40FF4FCAB4BA33B3142F7EB476E94BBBDA9BBB27A629084238A89C0A909E2A17383ED52CB488641935096C1E3A54D230A84F3599A5886ED44D0329E4115E07E26D38E87E25991011139DE9F8F5AF7E90706BCB7E275906582E80F990ED27DAB4A72B4ADDCCAAC6F0F437FE16F8A12DAF63D2EEA4CADD9C44DEADD81FF003DEBD92BE51D2EE5EDC413A64496F2ACA8476E735F52E9F7D16A7A75B5F43FEAEE23120F6CF6AEB83E879F35D4B34514568405145140051451400528A4A5140094514500145145001451450014514500145145007887C69D54CBAE5BE9CAC765B5B6E23B6F7E7F9015E4B68A44078EA6BADF89F76F77F103572321525108FA2A815CFDBAE21403B93591A58EF7C1B1008A3DB9AEF235007D2B86F0683B73F85776831CD71D4F88F4E969045B8F18AB089919A8208D9B1C6055C5D8BC67A7BD42453648910C7153245C6714D4C6719156546056AA262E4C84A1EC28C107A55B007B505148C815A720B9CACA48EB4D63F9D58D80F03141840C52E563E6457C12290C79AB2540A8CE31CD4B882914DD315011CE4D5D7E7355996B26B53452216C115C478F625934975C65BB576CFC5713E386FF00896B8EFDA85BA097C2CF32D381DA14746054E7D8D7BD7C2AD48DE7851AD1DF2F6729403D14F23F5CD782AFFA35B893241F3011F88AF50F8437E135EBBB407E4B9B7DE33EAA47F426BB63B9E6CB63D8E8A28AD8C828A28A0028A28A0029452528A004A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2803E62F8951087C7FAE6063F7C08FAB006B06DC816A093CF35D1FC5424F8F356C83933A819F408B5CC4583005EF9AC99A23D1BC19FF001EC0E39CF35DDC2BBD87A570DE0A42F66A7DFAD7758658895E1BD6B8E5F133D283F710EBBD452D94C7102F2770BDBEB58CD3DEBCA658A399971D00C66B4EDECBE6DC0EECF527BD6B430C11A65880A393934E2BB8DCADB1C98D6EEA39B63298703952A49A58BC4F7F04A04DB8C67A315E3F1AE96E758D0D0849AFED432F6F30122AACD79A3CC02895006E465700D53B74145DF7458B2D7FCF452CB82C3B56B4773E62E41AE5E58238FE687057B62B4B4EBA050293ED494D8E54D5AE8DC0D81B8F7E94D79F6A73D052647979CF359B7B3EC8B1DEAA53B19A8DD9625D4A1894963D3AD64DC78BAC230427CCDD3D6AABD8BDE29123E14FAD25B785B4EDFB9A4CB7A16E951CCD9A38463B8DFF0084B239064201ED4B078844F36CDBD3AE78ABA9E0DD295CC811998F5CB714B3F87AD1147930AA6DE4629B892A6B62D330740CBD08AE2BC6CB9D35F9C135D3596FB794DBC99D8DCA9F43E95CDF8F976E8F2B7A63F9D42DD0DE89A3C9F5090ADB40A7AB499FC2BD0BE12AEEF17DB64E365B3903F0AF3CBEC32D99EB8E48AF47F83C86EBC6534C14797059B11EC4903FC6BB5743CE7D4F73A28A2B5320A28A2800A28A2800A51494A280128A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A28A00F9F7E3469A6DFC671DC7245EC2AE3D8AFCA7F97EB5C1C49F291D81FCEBD3FE2EDD26A7736D2C6EAE2D77A851D403DFF00315E796F092625E4EF7FE558F3A7B1BBA72834A47A8F82EC8C3A4C6C47279AEA88079C671DAA8E8F08B6D2E18F1D1055A30866CE07E55C5296A7A118E962A6A9AC0D3ACFF75099676E12251924D7137FA7F88F5EB5B89B51927B7E3315B47C291EF5E8B0D8C68776C279CF1D5AAD84509F7703FBACBC5383B6E124AD647885AE93796EA206D31CAEEC991A3249EBC7A735E856BA5DAD9F87AD4249E5DD85CCA814B29F63EE2BAC658CF1B500CE78CD4125BC1C928315B395D58CE314A5CC73902ABC2DE5BB473852C114E41FF0AB7612BACF116EAC39FAD5C91460A43C023E638E83DAAB4087ED4840E178158CB7B1D4B53A549098C0E2B1EFE461305E3D066B522271D6B3AFD7372983834A5B1115A983A85C933790B2B48E78C29DAA3EA6B9BF1035FE93A840A2F41B574DCFF67C027D831C9AEFBECD14ED9740ADDF1C66AC8B0B7600490A381D03006B485B726ABE6D0F2FB2D675E96F9174BD4E658E473B52E083F28EEDD715D3E99E3C963BDFECFD66DCC72E7689907C8DEF5D545A4D82E76DAC60E739E29B7BA4D9DCC4639218F6FA003344E48CE2927A9332A4C56442083CF06B9AF1EDB97F0EDCB019C2D741696CD664448DF201819EC2AA78920FB57876F62C6498CE2B38BD47256D8F9FAF59B108EC11715EAFF0411BFB5753720FFC7B800E3FDB15E65730868ADF079008FCABDE3E137874693E184D42420CF7EA1F8FE1404E07F5AEE8EACF3A477D451456A66145145001451450014A2929450025145140051451400514514005145140053263B6090FA29FE54FA8AE7FE3D66FF71BF952635B9E49E23D363BBD36750BF300C49AE074887CED5AC62EC0D7AD3DBECB09A771BBCCC9C7A03D2BCE34487678AC8DA42C6481ED9AE24EC9A3D6C42E69C59E9F08022503A01C55A8B008F535562FB8335617839AC5948BC98039A4765CE0134D8D59BAF6A9C460AF4156913A22990CEDF2834BF675032D93577C9E7DA94A0C1E00ABE5072EC645C2F1B40FCAAB471E2451D31E953DD5CA6F644E48EB51DB2316DCFC13DAB37B9B2BA46AC43E5EBDAA8DF27EF15BB568C3165338ED515D4584208AA71D084D5CA9182782335602100E18D47692AABF9520E3B1AD45851B907F2A515714DD999F8607E6E7E82A64DAD9C60D58680E781513463B7047A537168574C6141CE4556B98F7DACB1766523F4AB2CD8E33F8D44DD718EB59ADC867855AD83DDEAB1DA2004B4A463D81C1FD2BDFBC213A1D30DA22145B7014293D3B7F4AF29F0C5929F175E1E71049264FA64D7ABF8517F7133FF78E7F535D506F9D2339538AC3CA4F7B9D0D14515D479C145145001451450014A29294500251451400514514005145140051451400535D3CC8DD0FF1291F9D3A8A00F3EBAB8F95AD597231B6B8F4B3FB3789E2754DB1CA060F5C15EBFCEBD0F52B0824D5E50D1F0ADB87E3CD624FA7F977EB21036A9CA0FEB5E7BBA7667B32946704D7A97630401C5581512F0054919C9ACDEE28B2F44700135723C7B5504600558127191D6B5831495C9A595546011CD50BAB9DB048C3A81493CD96DA0F350C830A549EBC1A6E772A3048AD6DE5470F9923282464926A05D52D2698A5ADD452B2FDE54704D23DA15F9762CF1F64638C5645D787ECA6B9FB54109B7BA439568CE39ACCDAC9EB73BC86E63FB2C7800311CD41A8DC471C439193EBDBDEB9D4BD9D618D7692CBF7A96E54DF6D697718D7FE599E327DFDAA9D46D58C552D6E68C135B4F1931CC8E41E769CD68432B0406B120B1557F336C716472B18EBF5AD34CEC233CF6A94EC54E28D38A40E9D71448063B66B3ADA7C3956386156DA5C826B572BA3271B3229463E95093FBC19F5A7C8F9A87AB0158F507B1CDF84F4F293EAD7520C1B8BA62B91FC3935DFE876FE458938C076C8FA7F9CD7190DD3C33982304E093D2BBFB3564B2815B8608335D346CE4D99E2D3A74947B93D14515D479A145145001451450014A292945002514514005145140051451400514514005145140181AD109A821C632832477E6B12FB9B98BDD4E6BABD4B4EFB6857460B2A7033D08F435CF6A3A75EC2F1CAF6FF00BB4C86752081F5AE5A907CCD9E851A90704AFA9507414FCFA77A8C1F996A6C6074AE496E744762CC2011ED53380919CFE150C1D053EE01DA31D68520DD9573B14B100B13C9A89E6C92481D68951B6E4E460679AAAB20DC4B3F51DE9DCD3726CB6E38E4FA7A52471BC8E30BB4F7CD466E23FEF73DEACC534783CB608F5AA516C1A63F728382A188EE6A09449B738C96FCE9B27D97EFE589FF007A9C2E63098FCB34DC243507B91C45C939247D0D5A490AB28CFE354DAE602321B07D29D14A92B80A6A354368BD38257CD4E5D7F5A9A19FCC881031EC6848999001D31447179701DDCF3DA8E633BA6AC46CD938F5A72FDE3DE88937483FD919A338622927EF112D8B36D6F1CB7702EC041619E3F1AE9AB9DD2D8A6A51A9E7208FD2BA2AEFA0BDD38B177E7498514515B1CA145145001451450014A2929450025145140051451400514514005145140051451400541789E658CE9D731B7F2A9E8A011E7F9F9B8EB572325B150DE43F67BF9A2C7DC738CFA76A58240C40CF23A8AF2E71B33D783BC6E5B806D18F7AB650B019AAA061855E8CFC9C524852672FE287D422457B5E235E5801D6AADB68D7F73134BF6E5703691B57AE7AFE55D2DF0EA48C8C60E7D2B9C669F4E95CDB48446DCED3574F9766691E669723B337A3F0920B8883DC48F191CF6E6AEC1E1784DCC8BBA50A318F98F354ECFC4EB3BC21D3CAC0C12790C7EBDABA3B6BB6688CADB7040C6C39AE9518F439AA55C44349192DE19B737423DD273CFDEE31531F0C59A5C20F2CB260E77126B504F9973B0F03AD51D575836908749225653CAC8092C3D0629D910ABD693514CA177E18B4304DB536313F2107A570DA86997367AC35B59DE3C8CC385EA14D74979E24BA9ACCC512E1D9B265C6D38CFA547A3DA6C2D7329DD2B9FBC6B19B8A3B29C6B4173547F2356C2D9EDED63576DD26D0093DCD589942C6062A44E82A2B87CE7DAB07B195EEC860036C8C7D71459422E6F16324856EA475C5337058B1EBCD5ED0E3DD73249FDD5C7E26AA8C79A689AB2E5836695A6990D9B99159DE4E9B9CF415728A2BD2492D11E74A4E4EF2614514532428A28A0028A28A0029452528A004A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A28039AF135B18DE3BC45E1BE490FA1EC6B120601F23B8AED7548567D2AEA3619FDD923EA3915E7D04C164C13D3D6B8EBC75B9DD869E9666EAFCCBCF5AB314BB545508240CA79071522B9E45729D0D166750EA7D0D65C96E1B28466B495C15C30CF6A6B202D914D15176461AD83C527AA75C7A569C114B1A1F227703FBB9C7E9569610DD7AD35E0639033C77ADE32B22DD6BAB4861B9D4241CCCEBC609500715464B68F2C6526473F89ABC23988032187B76A992D72727A5539F9046A463B7E06341605DC3B8DAA3A2D6AC2BB48006054ED1AA800520E0F15CF27A932A8E7AB2756C2D57958B71EBD6A4270951310AA49EB506688A66C0DB918AE8749B73058A9618793E66FE9FA5626996BF6FBDC9FF53110CFE84F615D4D76E1A165CCCE5C4CFECA0A28A2BA8E40A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A51494A280128A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A28A0064EBBADE55F5461FA579A5C407EFA1C30EF5E9AC32A47A8AF3ED9918C77C573623A1D78657B95AD2F46423707BE6B4BCC19045645CDB9DDB9090DD8D4715F151B64241E9CD7234759D086CE304559519158305F7EF3048DAA339F5AD7B5B859A3C8239F4A2C3B96D1950F5FAD48D2A1E322A011EF0769A745096E0F03EB571B834B726DC9C6318A0C800EB4184636D46D1ED18269BB92921ACC18F06A189A4676F300001C2FB8A460E24181F281C9A8A7B958863F88F02B268B7648B06404E73C0AA57373B80033ED8EB51CB73B1319F98D3614DC771E49A496A458E97C36BB6CE6E724B8273F4AD9AC8F0F9FF469C7A38FE55AF5E952F811E756569B0A28A2B4330A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A51494A280128A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A28A0028A2A1BCBB86C6CA6BB9D82C50A1763EC280399F1CF8CA2F0B69DB61DAFA84C0F9687A20FEF1FE9591632F9D04726721D0367EA335E4DE28D62E35AD62EAF2E1B2EFD17B2827803E8057A2784EEBED5E1DB17DD9611053F51C5736236475E13768D9962CF38ED599756BB8671C8F4ADCC6E5E955A6871D338AE53AD9CBCE92A11E8390DDC55BD3B57F298473101B3C62AFCF6CAE318CD62DDE9ED13E42165EA41A6990F4D51D859EA28FC123F3AD486E623800F26BCD2192488E239DA33FDC93A568C1AB5EC6B8F2C330EEA69A9587A33BE69541E587355E796319F9BA7415C87F6DEA2E9810AEEF76A824BBBB646134EAA7D23E48FCE872B8F447437FABC709F2E3F99CF1B456524CE5CC8F9F309FBA0F4AA96D1B48F98D0EE3D647EB8AD6B5B355009EB50D8D216084C982C38EC2B436630288A221B3DAA57C2D24522383C476FA15EDBC17785B7BB72A65FF009E6C3A13EDEB5DA672320E41EF5E25F102E04726991E7EF3393F4C015DAFC35F1136A9A39D3AE1CB5C5A0F9198F2F1F41F974FCABBE8BF711E76257EF19DC514515B180514514005145140051451400528A4A5140094514500145145001451450014514500145148EEB1A1791951072598E00FC68016BC9FC79E2BFED367D3ECE4FF00428DB0CE3FE5AB7F80ED5A3E36F1AA3A3E97A54C19586279D0F07FD953E9EA6BCDA42197A8E7D6901CEDC125AE0E73F3819FA0FF00EBD775F0D2F849677762C7E689F7AFFBADFF00D715C03BE4DD0F4909AD5F06EA8BA6788A2676C473298DF3EFD2B2AAAF166F425CB347B745D3A734AF186078E2A382459143035615782C3F2AE24CF4199CE9863C7D29862126411C8F5AB73A1249039A85305C714EC4B332EB464946E518359ADA2DD21F91C81D706BB48911D7A0AB1F654206467EB4D23367111E8B76EBF3C9B7DEB42D7C3F1A00CE4BB1EE6BA836C00C019A6B461171D0D26868CE8ED123F976E3F0A9634F98E0F3529EB5246BE9516344204DA09A89CE6AC13CD65EAF7F0E9D632DCCCDB52352C4D32E279AFC42BE137896D6D94E45BC596FAB1CFF002029BE17D667D175E1750B0CC6F8656E8CAC3915CA4F7B2EA5AB4F7B2FDF9A4DD8F41D87E55A36AE3FB4255EA4A822BBE9C6D148F2EB4B9A6DA3E94D2757B4D6ACFED16AFD3878CFDE43E87FC6AFD784691AF5DE8B791DDDABE0E00743F75C7A1AF58D1FC63A4EAC91AF9EB6F70C398A538E7D01E86B43237E8A28A60145145001451450014A2929450025145140051451400514557BEBFB4D36DCDC5EDC470443F89CE33F4F5A00B155AF750B4D36033DEDC47047EAE7AFD07535E7FAEFC50DBBA1D1A0F6F3E71FC97FC6BCEB51D56FB529DA7BCB996690F763FE71480F4AD6FE28C30068F4AB6DE738F3A6E9F50BFE35C2EA1E24D4B5B72F7B7724880F11E70B9F6038AC02C40F5278AB200450BE9D7EB400F3212DC9FAD34E09F5A3273FE1428DE4E28039890E2FAE93D4D537CAB706AD6A07CBD5A418E180355A5033C5203D17C11E3500A69DA8BE18E16299BBFB1F7AF4E8A50CBC57CD0A4839AF4AF04F8DFE68F4DD4E5E7858A66EFF00EC9FF1AE6AB4BAA3B68D6BFBB23D464019491F7AA9104B607153F99C0C74A4C073D7E9581D16085BCB6C1EF5A50CA081CD515418C1E0FA1A9150A9E0D589D997DDC01559C9639A728247CC734BD3A0C527A896840D1E0824FE14A3273C53DBDCD4324A154F350CB4C259022939E71F957947C46D6CCCF1E9B1BFCA4EF900F4EC2BB0F12F88A0D26C9E495B2C461133CB1AF17BCBB9350BD96E66399246C9F6F6AD68D3BBB9957A9C91E5EAC2DC61C35685930FED5EBD63AA5180800A9B4F707598C632769AEC479E744AC36E29E92100AB72A6A1604673CF34A0F1914C4741A478BF59D1088E1BB3242BFF002C66F9971FD3F0AEFB48F891A6DE6D8F5089ACE4EEE3E7427F98AF2224B019E48A5538638FAD007D1B6F7305DC2B35B4C9344DD1E36C8A92BE7FD3B59BDD3271359DC490B772A783F51DEBBED17E24872B16AD08F4F3A11FCD7FC2981E854556B2D42CF5287CDB3B88E65EFB4F23EA3A8AB3400528A4A5140094557BCBEB4D3E0335E5C470460672ED8CFD077FC2B88D5BE27DA405A3D2ED8CEDDA59BE55FC0753FA5007A063358DAAF8A747D1C1173788D28FF96317CEFF0090E9F8D790EA9E31D6F562CB35F3A45DE387E45FD3AFE35866407D7DCD203BFD5FE27DE4BB934DB74B64E81DFE773FD07EB5C35F6A577A8CED71773CB34A7BC8C4FF00FAAAAE79CF34BB7D7AF5C668018DC1CF3ED4C2C718E2A6231C541236073D3DA9804403CB93C85AB180467144516D8957B9EB52140383EBDA9011E4820D390F5EF4D3F4A72F0076E7AD3039AD7E331DFC72606186335473915B7E248F75BA3839DA7358719040A402ED04533186E73528EB4D71C5033BDF08F8E9AD82586AB21687858A76EABECDEDEF5E9D0CCB22875604119041CE457CE238AEAFC2DE32B8D15D6DEE0B4D624F4EAD1FBAFF0085615297589D54ABF491EE11B2BAFCD532A7A1CD62586A905E5BA5C5BCAB2C520CAB29AD14BA0C301856074DBB1780E3A5359F02AAB5D85E335565BC2C719C0A4C39596259B1F2E79AE7BC45E22B6D16C9A5998173C2203CB1AA1E22F16DAE871329224BA23E5881E7F1F415E4DA96A575AADDB5CDDC85DCF41D947A0ABA74DCBD08A95953D16E3F54D56E758BE6BABA7C93F757B20F4155E250324D44064D585C05E2BA924B4381B7277623310BD79A4D224275C8FF00DD34D90D3B4319D710F600D52133AB93B64F3D3EB4C1D31C5492A9CFA1FAD464118EA4D021EB81D4FD3141CF3D7E948A71C8A7F5E707F9D30101E3A54884AF538C5443E623B0EE2941C938CD0068D95FDC59CAB35B4EF14ABD1D1B06BBBD1FE23CABB62D521128FF009EB1E037E23A1FD2BCD94E39C1C83EB4A84EEE01F5CD007BFE9FADE9DAA28369751BB1FF009664E1C7E06B42BE7A8AEA488AF278E841E47D2BA8B1F1A6B105B08C5F160A78F31031C7D4F3401C96A3A85DDFDD34B757124B21272CEC4E2A9E3279A795F9DB8E734D0B8F4CD201BB4038F5A5038F5A7E0000E38F7EB4D0A3A5001B79C76EF9A7E79271903DE8EF8DB8FEB48DC28C1F7A6031987F09FAD44AA659BB155E695DB0BEF4FB6DA611B48627EF7B1A009C201D40A6139CE69E5C0E00E2A2273C2F3400BB739EB4A7E5200E4D359B6FCA0FCDFC8D3118904E39CF5A008354877E9F271CE0D72509E0576D7196818631C57158DB23AFA3114809FB6690F22914F6341A061B734DC62A40334A40C50069E85E23BDD06E7740DBE163FBC858FCADF4F43EF5EBDA26B567AE588B9B490F1C3C7FC487D0D78601CE6AD58EA779A45D19ECA53148CBB4FA11EF594E9A96A8DA95671D1EC7B95DDFDB58C465BAB88E251FC523015C1F887C7E8375BE93F331E0CEC381F415C8DA69FACF8AF50710CCB7572ABBFCB7994311FEC8279FC2A8CB6EF04EF14A312236D61E84528D14B5654F10DE911B2CB2DCCAD34CED248C72598E49A455C9A52B838A78E0715AD8E76C5D985E3AD0A7029493D0D340E4E78A00639C8AB1A0A13AA338C12077AAED57BC3F9FB5CDF85342674B229607A54382B8CF03D2AC331278E83F5A8D86E3D00EF4C045C0C8E9ED4A3078C9C7D690F3DB38A453EF8FC2801AC304B7AD3C13C1E31EF43ED452EE7FFAF446498F0463B8E6801C011DFA76A7024F503EB9A400B2F2C73DE973C8C76F5A600783CD5AB771E59C9E73E95588E84F39F6A9635F94E01C669010151BC9C9EA69303271CE3BD3E4FF005878C60D373B718EB9EB400846072700D03AF3CFB52B0C9A5238DDC73C50034E7B6334D7C91D31CFA53BD7814C276FCB9FA8A0444E85B8C702A9CA92452F99136D6EFE87EB578B82085E49ED4C16ECE4971B47EB40C8E0BE49DB6C8BE5C9E98E0FD2ACFDE3F2F029C96D146095500F73D4D03D01C50044460F149820E31C1A7B0DC4E3814CCF1C75068026C62220F5C57177236DF4C3FDA26BB55CB752335C86A6BB354947AE08A1810A9E29D4D51C53C5200CE0D3B19EB49DEA7B5B59AF2EA2B5B7469269582A2A8C924D004124B15BED79559D370CAA9C16F500D76E60F08F8CECE38F4EB74D37548D00007064FF007933F31F7539F6ABF73F0F6CA1D323B7D76DA6B19C1222D5AD2433C2D9ED2276FC307DAB87D7FC19AB786CC77132A4F6321FDCDFDAB6E89FD391F74FB1C1A1810EB1E1DD5FC38EB3CF62A210DF25DC0C5933F51F74FB1C1AB177E29BBD7EDE34D4EDA396EE20156F106D91C7A3FF0078FBF5AEA7C21E319622B61AF3FDA2D241B3ED122EF641E920FF00968BF5E4763573C59E04B7D3617D6348402D061A7815B70881E8E87BC67F4A4981E7FC30F7A403079A8DEE10DD6DE81BA7D6A43CB7BFA5318A4934DC734E1C76A0F5E280227E957BC387FD22E0919C11546438539ABFE1AFF59367B9142133A4241FE1C7A5386DE724629A78207A0CD1C6C231DFB5301E7681918FA546ECA8A18E001D4D3B04F7E00CD38283C7502988CF25AE640EC708BF747F5AB6140DA41A468003B97AFA53C71C1EB40C78072401C9F5A41EFD0D286E8476EE69AD8248273E94002918273CD5A831B09C1E4F6AAC09CE7F954D1394523DFD280227F99C8F7CE6A323E61EE6A4707CC3EB9ED4D66032768E29084E7248E94A464918E075A14719FC69369C1386FF001A603791D8FD7AD4172E5636DA7E603AD4CD9E80F1EF50CA01041E9DE8027B765F2D766002323DEA5EE723B67154AC0E6231FF00CF3623FC2AF01D0AE2801802AE79C64669833D0726A5DBB739C533A9A008882783834D00027207E34E627A74151A8049EB8F6A432CA9C6707A7A5727AEAECD490FF796BA98BDFA0F5AE73C509B25865039068623354F14F14C4C15C8E98CD380E47AD218F5F7AB7A5EADA769BAAC7F6F4BB2A4644B6920592139E187AFD38AA6D88D0B9E83F53E95962D24B9B96D873331C853FC5EC3DE803E8AD1BC5727D83ED32CE9ACE92DF2BDEC0BFBC8FDA68CF5FC7F3AD88F45B596DDEF3427866B2BA189EC5BE6B79C77001FBADEC79F4AF9B346D6752F0FEA02EB4FB892DEE17861D98775653C11EC6BDAFC09E28B2D76E0C9A704B0D5587FA56984FEE6E40EAF17A1EF8EA3B509EA339FF17F82D7458CEA9A6A3FF67B361E26E5AD98F63EABE869FE03F16E66FEC1BCC488EAC2D83F46047CD09FF658671E86BD635158EF2CE46110994A149A16FF00968BDD4FB8F5AF9BFC5FA5CBE15F1029B5998DBB91716530EBB73C7E208C1FA5262454F18E93FD83E269ECE125AD89135BB1EF1B723F2E9F8555B39FCD8C17FBE3EF7BD69F8C7598F5FD52DAE23006D814311D99BE623F024D62A298B6BAF51DBD685B0CD23EB8A43C669A8E2440C0F07A539A98114C32BC77AD1F0E1C4D3301E959B3B6067D0715A7E1A18926CF6C53423A323058F7C518C8C91CD2838EF9CF34E61C6473EB40840ADB724D19EA470691D84519627E526A38EE637182E37771D29812FF00C0BDA9B83CE453B8EDF8D200318A0069C28EF4BF771807DE9922E5003EB5230F90F3C50319B8EFE01E956603FBBEBDEAB36401F313562023CBFBB9E680226FBCDC73BBA537664E4FD49A7BF32301EB4857FBBD7340814718C72280C40E690E71D7927AD213C633400D3B8609A8A4C7271D7F954A4823FF00AD4C2BFBBCE68029DB1F2EF4AF389173D7B8AD34E87273E959736E8E58A4C7DD6F4ED5A48C3B66801EC3907B9EB4C619241CE4F6A5E7A9E39A46E79CD0042CBCEDC8A4C90411DBB629597E6240F6CD20E09CF1DF34864919E08C561F899736E9EA1AB701F907F4ACBF10A03A7B1C64820D0C47356A7E4C1EDC558C1C8C753D2A9C1F7F6FF7B8AB723145F2C6379E0FB0A432299B7B051F717F53EB558AFEF1707073C1F4AB2DF2AD57670A771ED401D55868C3C656412C87FC4E605DD264610A0E3E76EC7D0F7E95662F00F89746BC59844AB3429E7978A603C90A32599891B715E9DF0E3458347F0B5BCB082D737C05C3BB8DBDB8273D140E99FAD721E3FF00170D5125D1F4B90FF6786FDFCE3ADD30FF00D90761DFAD16B01BDE0FF88B17885DE19891A9C3117940181728BD580ECE3AFBD711F142E6DEE6EE0B78195E32FF006984AF40AE3E603DB2335CFF00867C3F75AD7886382D9DA1863FDE5CDC02408A21F78923D4718EE4E2B47C796B0597898410487CBF215920239B75249543EF8C1FC6A7A8CE6228BA7153B28C6295050E302A84471B7932609F909FC8FAD5F1C8CD51601D0D49693160626E5D4617DC50319390C5547739FC2B6BC383E6B8F6C561B7339EF8E056EF8748F3E6EDC8A6846F76E3D297B6724629C7AF07826800007DB8E9408301D406C1F6AAD25946C72B953E839156D07209A42C7711C7E069814A34B8B77009CC6474CE7FFD5568005471D7BD48DCB6D3E9C7151B282DDB8F7A006CA732A28E78A776C1CE4531FF00D7E31C8C54A41241A0631BE5233DEA6B70BE59C8EFDEA171EC01A920E10F04F3400A48DE727B9E94600E074A523058E463A5260123BD0211B1C01CD31BAF00600A71197E69B8DC4F031D28019C8E08C5249D38E7F0A7E7AD46C7E6A00AD7281D1947A75A9ADDC3DBA311CE39A57518F5A82DBE5DF1E790723E86802E9248CF149D88A542186D34857D0FE740119DA3193C8F4A69EBDB03D2A42AB9FAF7A43C76EA3E94862A803E53DCD53D690BE972F6C0AB8A7902A2BF8F759CAA73F74D023854FBD56630076AACA306AC4679A43125E168D32C5F55D6ACEC1012679557819EA69B3B002BB4D363B7F08E8B0EA1E403ADDD022191CFCD0E47551DB0A7AF5C91401D678F3C522D206F0F6992004288EF2643D80C794BEC3BFE55C3691A3DDEBDA8C5A7D8C7BA693A93C2A2F7663D80A8E1B5B8D42F22B6B789E6B899C2A22F2598D7B069D61A57C3FF000BCF7178EB230C7DAA543CDCCBD44319FEE8EE7F1A00CAD565D23E1C7851520559A490E61571F35ECC3FE5A3FF00D335EC3FFAF5E2134F737F753DFDCBBCB2CB2169256EEC79AD2F156BF7BE24D665D46F9C176F95117EEC483A228F415D55A78705AF80B51374A5654B64BA718E56466CA29FF80E0FE353D467131F4A7B2FCA69919E01A95CE56A845743DA865039EF401F352C9400D8979F6ADFF0EE049393D320561C43835BDE1D1CCE7FDAA680DD23278071480F5F989A7E7E5383CD346319FE54085191CFEA29C76F427F1C528E3A372074C500E7B649E6980CC64920D20C93806970A48CF514050791F8500349CCAE47AF6A9368DA33DBAD44BC8CE39CFE15229E79C508631B19C63247AD4B0E761E40E6A27C1239E4FAD490950878CF3D85021E48F9BA75A418DDD3927348E36330A07098E33FCA8108D819E73ED51139240E062A46C6083CE2A238CFB1340C71238A6E3739078ED4A70070793403C640CD0046E00380411F4AAA0EDBBF665C67DEAE119C6073DCD54B8182AE3A86CD005A46E29DC670BDF9A895883CF3F5A99946CDD9E4D003581C8E7EB4D6E00C76E94EE0AE29A4E78E82800CED26A4917CC84E0678EF50F7F71D7356010613CE7B62803CF241B6575F4635345CF4A4BE5297B3A91D1CD1074A919A9A0E9E351D7ADE2750D1A1F31C762179C1F6CE3F5A8F58D58EADAF3488E5A08FF7711FEF0CF2DF89C9FCA8B5D44596997B1404FDAAEB1133FF00722EA40F763C7D07BD75DF0CBC286E6F63D6AE60591124D9650B8F96494725DBFD841C9F7C500773E0BF0E47E1DD31F53D49960BD6877CD230FF008F3848E9FF005D1BD3A8CE2BCFFC6BE2697C45A80601A1B1B7CA5AC19E157FBC7D58F735B9E33F152EAD31D2B4F99A4D3E172D2CDDEEA5EEE7FD91D87E35CE68FE1EB9F126B096301F2D00DF3CCC3E58631D58FF004F534010F843C3D1DF5CCBACEA3116D2EC181F2CFF00CBCCDFC310F5F56F6FAD7A6EA3666DB47B6B5D4486B9D46F04F780F655F9DC7D00551F9D6CE95A3DA2A5BB451AC1A4E9C08B4493A330FBD33FA9EE7DF02B86F1DEBE1747BCD4C92AD7AAD61A6C6C7E61167F7B29FAF4CFAB1F4A9921A3CACDC2DC4D24C8A111DD9828E8A09C81521E56B3ED8E015F4ABE394AA02303E6A24E4D0A79A6B1CB714089A3C05ADDF0E6364FC7F17F4AC3C6D415BBE1B03C894F425C8CE69A036CE0F6FA8A41F7BDA9CD95071D33C1A0025FD47AD0217DF278A3E600B0C71C53874E7A534819E99CF4A6023678CFA7A51850BDB03D0D047CE383F4CD237DC73EDD31400C5C989724FD314E52320FAD391405C1FAD38631C0C9A008D946086C023A54909DA8402719F5A6363A93D78E29D1AE54F03AD003DF3E6373819A69CB71C648E6948667386EFDA9A46E272706810D6CF7C1A839278FC2A7700707A8AAA3396CFAD0344E010B818E98E690718073CF7A45CB70453F8CF4C6D1400C0700E1AA3957CC47E3B75A9362E3D0FA5211CE07208E68020B7625149EBD2AC8E4118E2ABC6A04AEA7D7233DAACAF5DB9E9400D38048E9CFA534F390339A7F439033EF48E39CD0033EF718A9A305931C0CD440F3935221C92391480E27594F2F559C0E84E6A0B7FB9577C40BB7546F75154A004C3C024F603BD219AFE18D0A4D7F54FB386F2E05CC97136388A31D4FD7B0F52457A1F8C35C8F42D31742D3904171342239114F36B6DD562FF7DBAB7D7DE974D8AD7C07E0D5B899524BC720953FF2DEE7190BFEE479C9F56AF3B334F7D772DCDCC8D2CF3397776E4B313480D1D22C6E350BC86CED2232CF336C4403A9AF6FD0BC356FA4E9BFD9B036EC90F7D72A3995FB2AFB0E807E359BE07F0A1D0AC84B3A0FED6BA8F2FBB8FB34479DBEC48E4FA74AEBE666B78520B407CE7E221DC67AB9F73DBD055A4230FC437313C52D81996D74FB64F32FE71F7628D7A20F5F4F7635F3C78B7C40FE24D71EEFCBF26D63510DA41DA2887DD1F5EE7DC9AED3E2378A23BACE83A5CBBACA19375CCEA7FE3E651FFB2AF6F5EB5CEF81BC2BFF000926BC0DCA37F665A625BB61FC433F2C63DD8F1F4C9A8651B29E15165F08DEFE6091DCCD2A5E3B38F98467E48D07B9C96C7B8AE290FCB8AEF7E2EF88775D41E1D81940B7713DE04FBBE6E30B18F645E3EA6BCFE13914201A38269ABCBFE34BD18D2C3CB5311331C0ADEF0E28FB2B9238DE6B9F73D6BA2F0E7FC79F4FE2269A066CE4AAE07AD19DAD8007F8D07248C77ED40C9C93802810E0CD827B76E28182016EA29491B7078E7AE681C7BD30180E5BF1FC6924394E4F538E6970093914C906022E3BF7A009768C06639FA5203B72DB4E29FD62E3191E948589EA7B7A50046572CC1781EF52C0008F9F5F5A898ED20E39FAD4F06761FAD3026F29031C2F7A1E240385EB451480AF2C69B41C738F5A8C449FDDEF451400F4893238EDEB4796BB18E3B8EF451400EF2D3D283126FE9FAD145022BBC482E970BDAA648931D3F5A28A062BC4983F2F6A431271C7EB451400C1121DD91D3DE9E235DDD28A2901CC789608FF00B414EDE76FA9AA365122AC6CA3043020E7DE8A290CECBC7A4BF8896D589305B5B44B0A678405431FCC9249AB5F0D6C2D6E3C5B69E742B208D1E550DC80CA09071DF07D68A2840CF6BD3544912BBFCCD2CD8727F88019C1FC6B9EF175D4F0783F55BA8A5649DD9223203CED638600F6C8A28AB7D40F03B8823C9F97F5AF6CF03DAC1A7F81B4E92D6258DDEDEE2ED88E774CB9018E7AE0018ED451598CF9FAE07DA6692798B492C8C5DDD9892C4F249AB56D0C7B47CBDBD68A2840C6B431E4FCBFAD3E1823DDF77F5A28A6215A18F27E5FD6BA4F0FC118B0FBBFC47BFBD1450819AFE5261BE5EFEB48224C0F97F5A28A62078D42A8C7BF5A72C498FBB4514C00429B54EDE49E6A19517ED0463A5145004BE5260F1FAD46635C118FD68A2980890C67AAF7F5AB1046BB5B8FE2A28A00FFD9";
    
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( photo.getBytes());
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\test.jpg");
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int readBytes = 0;
    while ((readBytes = is.read(data)) > 0) {
      out.write(data,0,readBytes);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    is.close();
```

What if I get the string like that, it looks like not the hex

String photo = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/7gAOQWRvYmUAZAAAAAAB/+EUhkV4aWYAAE1NACoAAAAIAAsBDwACAAAABgAAAJIBEAACAAAAFAAAAJgBEgADAAAAAQ....."

Comment: use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java to convert your hex string to byte array

Comment: Have try that, not work for me. the generated file stil get "file is damaged, corrupted or too large"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `0x` with `substring` and convert hex string to byte array :

```
try {

    String photo =
            "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";

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(hexStringToByteArray(photo.substring(2)));
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/home/bmartel/test.jpg");
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int readBytes = 0;
    while ((readBytes = is.read(data)) > 0) {
        out.write(data, 0, readBytes);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    is.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

With `hexStringToByteArray` picked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java) :

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        System.out.print(data[i / 2] & 0xFF);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    return data;
}
```

For Base64 data use :

```
Base64 base64 = new Base64();
byte[] data = base64.decode(photo);
```

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, that works for the hexString. But I have some other data with the value looks like not the hex, I have update in the post. Can you help to figure what it is and how to generate jpeg ?

Comment: pretty thanks, Bertrand. I get the base64 and insert into my sql database, using convert(varbinary(max),photo), which will convert my base64 value to binary and store in db, but after this transform, the data I get from db is looks like hex, which I could not generate the correct jpeg file. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Can you give the code you use to convert base64 to byte array and to store in database so i can reproduce the problem ?

Comment: sql="update talbename set image=convert(varbinary(max),"+photo+") where id=1;"

Comment: the base64 string was converted into varbinary and strore in db, but that could not be generated as a jpeg file. but the original base64 string is good. I think it could be transform problem when insert into db

Comment: Hi Bertrand, why some of the hexstring will get the error of "String index out of range" when calling the hexStringToByteArray function

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink your problem differently, if you look for Q/A about best way to store image file to mysql, you will see that most people say that it is recommended not to store them in database but in a filesystem & store their filename in database as you want. You will get more performance if you store them in a filesystem.